# Can a science educator teach math?

Tags: general-pedagogy

I don't mean to sound rude and denigrating to math educators but I always imagined that a science teacher (physics/chemistry), who has to know math, would be eligible to teach math?

Ignoring the pedagogical differences and the fact that there are far less science teachers than math teachers, content wise strictly speaking, isn't a science teacher thus then qualified to teach math? Is there something a math teacher can do that a science teacher cannot?

The only parts of math that science teachers probably cannot do as well are abstract math, number theory and statistics and probability.

Am I wrong in this thinking?

Comment: Why should we "*[ignore] the pedagogical differences*"?

Comment: A mathematics teacher has to know the language the students use.  Does that make them qualified to teach that language?

Comment: Well, yes, as you already acknowledge, "up to a point". Just as high school math teachers can teach high school physics up to a point. These are the two closest things. In fact, the basic chemistry "stoichiometry" has a lot in common with "number theory", and little to do with calculus.

Comment: “Eligible” and “qualified” could be interpreted to mean that the person would be permitted to under the policies of a particular school or school system. I imagine it varies by school.

Comment: I think accreditation for at least some USA schools allows for engineering PhDs to teach math in the university provided they have taken 18 or more hours of mathematically focused graduate hours.  Is that a good thing ? Debatable.

Comment: Which level of education are we talking about here? This is different in kindergarten and at university...

Comment: Even many math majors graduate without much clue of what mathematics really is.  They may not truly understand that mathematics is about inference, not executing algorithms.  I would image that many science educators would earn their degree without ever being expected to produce a proof of a theorem.   It would be disturbing for such a person to teach mathematics, because (while they may be proficient with using some of its results as tools) they do not know what the subject is even about.

Comment: If a math class consists mostly of students who will be using that math in physics/chemistry courses, it may actually make sense for a science teacher to teach that class, since they know what tools will be useful and can bring in application questions from those classes.

Comment: Well, if the science educator understands the math then yes...? I'm assuming you're talking about stuff like high school algebra and not Galois theory though, so it's hard to really answer.

Comment: I'm reminded of Polya's commandments about good teaching, one of which can be paraphrased as "know your subject". The question isn't in what someone is trained, it's what they know. Unfortunately, most not trained in math don't know enough math to teach it well.

Answer (score 8):

That depends on the level. In general the rule is that to teach a subject coherently, one needs to know roughly speaking five times more than one is going to present to the students. If this condition is satisfied, then you should be just fine (the little quirks like what would be the best way/order to present this or that can be picked up on the way and there is no universal agreement on them anyway). If not, you'd rather leave it to other people. I acted as a tutor in elementary physics a couple of times (kinematics and dynamics: Newton laws, energy/momentum conservation and such) and I felt completely comfortable with that though I'm a pure math professor, and the results were satisfactory too, but I wouldn't go into, say, teaching quantum mechanics though I am not totally ignorant of it.

So just evaluate your knowledge and make the conclusion yourself. I have no doubt that you'll be fine teaching addition of fractions but I have my reservations about letting you teach a graduate university course in measure theory (though I don't know you well enough to declare that you are disqualified from it, of course). Just follow that 5 to 1 rule and you'll be well within your competence level, that's all.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for *"In general the rule is that to teach a subject coherently, one needs to know roughly speaking five times more than one is going to present to the students"*? I don't doubt its essence for a second (though I'm unsure about the precise factor), but I would love to show this to those of my students who intend to become math teachers and keep asking why they have to learn all those things which they believe they "won't need in school anyway".

Comment: @JochenGlueck I wish I would but I don't at the moment. The factor is not precise, of course (after all, how exactly do you measure?), but it is roughly in that area. If you look at old university textbooks in various subjects, they contain the amount of material about 5 times more than one can possibly squeeze into a one semester course. I believe in the general principle though without any reference. If it is violated, we get homework problems asking to find the area of a triangle with sides 5,6,7 and altitude 4 to the side 6 (my daughter brought that masterpiece from school once).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Her geometry teacher was not stupid at all, but they were learning just the triangle area formula and the students were still confused about which side to multiply by the altitude, so he decided to give them all three choices to check understanding. Now, one *can* create a triangle with not too large integral sides and one integral altitude, but that requires some knowledge *beyond* the triangle area formula (though not too advanced). As to the (future) math teachers, they may meet some smart kids occasionally and those can ask questions of all sorts.

Comment: That's indeed a good anecdote; it illustrates the problem quite vividly. Regarding future highschool teachers: That they will sometimes have to teach smarts kids is of course a valid point - but I'm under the impression that many students are told this all the time as *the* reason why the have to learn so much advanced math. I understand why they don't find this, as a sole reason, completely convincing, and thus I very much prefer to explain the reasoning to them which you mentioned in your answer: in order to teach properly you need to understand much more than you teach.

Comment: @JochenGlueck There is yet another way to look at it as far as the education of future teachers is concerned: in every subject, the students (except, perhaps,  the brightest ones) fully comprehend and retain forever only a fraction of what they are exposed to, i.e., to have them to master simple things at the ace level, one needs to make them struggle for some time with more advanced ones. I have no reference for that either, but if you have ever taught some course that requires a prerequisite and that prerequisite was taken some time ago, you can easily decide whether I'm right or not :-)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there something a math teacher can do that a science teacher
> cannot?

The essence of the mathematical discipline is *rigorous deductive proof*. Feel free to read that as "correct and understandable explanations and justifications" for mathematical principles.

Frequently, non-math science teachers have only taken computational math courses in college, like calculus, differential equations, and linear algebra (likely in their first two years or so).

But for college math majors, there is a radical shift around the end of the second year: courses suddenly shift to being about *writing and understanding proofs* as their central focus (generally talking U.S. system here; in other locales they wouldn't wait that long). It's common for math majors who are only good at mechanical calculations to find this very difficult or switch to another major as a result. Science majors usually never see these courses. (Conversely, some people who would be very good actual math majors never get through the mechanical-calculating prerequisites to get to this point.)

So it's quite likely that science teachers, given their background, could present a calculating algorithm, but be unable to explain *why* the method works. Not being trained and practiced in how to carefully attend to starting definitions and theorem-construction, it's quite likely that it would come out as a mishmash and be unclear on what the symbols, operations, starting assumptions, and sufficient and necessary conditions really are (in fact: I often experience this when I try to read posts on SE Physics, say).

Overall, such a mode of presentation represents [cargo-cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) (or faith-based) math, and leaves students unable to succeed at the next level, because all they're doing is memorizing a ton of separate facts instead of understanding more broadly-applicable principles.

Comment: *could present a calculating algorithm, but be unable to explain why the method works* -- A good example is being able to answer a question such as [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4460967/13130) (see my comment there), including being able to answer appropriate to the student's mathematical background level.

Comment: In case that MSE question gets closed, and thus viewable only to those with sufficient reputation: **Question** Is there away we can prove say the division rule for indices with the same base? What is the intuition behind it? eg. 2^a/2^b=2^(a-b) **My Comment** What type of numbers are $a$ and $b$ -- positive integers with $a \geq b,$ integers, rational numbers, real numbers $\ldots$ ? For the intuition, try an example, such as $a=5$ and $b=2$, replacing exponents by repeated multiplication and then reducing the fraction by ordinary arithmetic properties of fractions: *(continued)*

Comment: $\frac{2^5}{2^2} = \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{2 \cdot 2} = \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{1} \cdot \frac{2 \cdot 2}{2 \cdot 2} = \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{1} \cdot 1 = \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{1} = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 2^3 = 2^{5-2}.$

Comment: I just realized I left a step out in my original comment: $\ldots \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{2 \cdot 2} = \frac{(2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2) \cdot (2 \cdot 2)}{(1) \cdot (2 \cdot 2)} = \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{1} \cdot \frac{2 \cdot 2}{2 \cdot 2} \ldots$

Comment: I like this answer: a math teacher can explain more concretely about polynomials than a science teacher who just happens to know how to solve those.

Comment: Replying to your comment "It's common for math majors who are only good at mechanical calculations to find this very difficult or switch to another major as a result. Science majors usually never see these courses."  Indeed---I think that working physicists are often *much* better at, for example, integration than the average mathematician.  Physicists are typically *very* good at computation, but often have no idea of why it is that their computations work (other than having some intuition about a physical process which, again, the mathematician may lack).

Answer (score 2):

It's common in Madrid and mostly a failure, although there are of course individual exceptions. Most trained in something other than math don't know math well enough to teach it well. It's not so different from what happens when mathematicians have to teach computer programming. They can do it, those who don't have criteria by which to judge (students, parents, administrators, politicians) can't much tell the difference, but the result isn't what it could be (I speak from the experience of having taught C programming quite a few times).

Answer (score 2):

As long as the science teacher is appropriately motivated, I can't see why on earth he or she would not be able to teach mathematics to at least high-school level.

In order to reach a certain level of scientific sophistication as to be able to understand the science syllabus in order to teach it, there is *bound* to be at least a modicum of the "important" stuff in mathematics: namely, how to recognise a proof and how a proof is structured.

At the level of high school mathematics, it should not take a prohibitively long time to reach a level at which they can impart the knowledge and skill -- but as I say, the teacher has to be *motivated*.

If it's the level of: "we haven't got anyone to teach maths, we cast lots and you're it," is very probably *not* going to work well.

Comment: At my [undergraduate institution](https://catalog.unr.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=47&poid=129422), physics majors are required to take calculus, DEs, and PDEs (no proofs-based courses).  At my [PhD institution](https://physics.ucr.edu/academics/undergraduate-program/degree-requirements), physics majors must take calculus and DEs (PDEs is not required)---again, no proofs based classes.  Hence your assertion that "there is bound to be at least a modicum of the "important" stuff in mathematics: namely, how to recognise a proof" does not mesh with my experience.

Comment: @PrimeMover If some of these answers and comments were really true then I'd agree. After all, if no "real" math or even a single proof is ever seen until well into college, why would the teacher need to know proofs?

Comment: @Thierry A teacher is expected to be expert enough in their field to help advise and guide students who may eventually do more in that field.  I would expect that anyone teaching calculus should have an idea of what comes *next*.  Where do the results from a high school calculus class show up again?  How do we know that these results are even true?  When and where were these results first understood?  By whom?  Someone whose highest mathematical education is a calculus class is (in my opinion) unqualified to teach calculus.  Thus a typical physics major isn't going to cut it.

Comment: This is why most states in the US require that secondary mathematics instructors have training in mathematics beyond just calculus.  While I have some serious qualms with the minimal level of these requirements, Arizona, California, and Nevada *all* require that mathematics instructors take several upper division mathematics courses, and demonstrate an understanding of basic mathematical ideas (the structure of a proof, for example).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sure, teachers need to know their subject. That's obvious, but the question isn't specifically about calculus. I see no reason that a physics teacher wouldn't be able to teach 9th grade algebra. Surely they know enough of what comes next, or at least as much as a typical high school math teacher, who will typically not be good at math (it's fairly common for them to not know calculus, as I've personally observed)

Comment: @Thierry Okay, so consider examples from algebra.  Why do we study polynomials?  What is significant about the roots of a polynomial?  How do you know that roots even exist?  What is special about polynomials of degree less than four, and how do we know that?  What is the significance of the analogy "integers are to rationals as polynomials are to rational expressions"? How far can one push that analogy?  Circling back to the beginning, **why do we care about polynomials**? These are the kinds of questions that someone trained in mathematics ought to be able to answer, but others likely can't.

Comment: Don't get me wrong---I think that the training that mathematics teachers in the US get is, very often, quite inadequate (I say that as someone who once held a a secondary ed teaching credential in mathematics---I know very well how my colleagues were trained).  Still, someone trained to teach mathematics is far more likely to have engaged with the history and context of mathematics than someone trained to teach chemistry or physics.  A chemist might know how to compute, but the mathematician will know *why* to compute.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Overall I really agree with your basic point and I admit I'm leaning more into the devil's advocate side as I normally would, but I actually think someone with a good physics background would be great for teaching 13 year olds polynomials. They're good for modeling real world stuff, and they could even hint at Taylor series as being useful for approximating things like pendulum periods. I don't think questions about existence of roots requiring the least upper bound axiom or something similar are appropriate or beneficial at that stage, and even I have no idea (cont.)

Comment: what's special about polynomials of degree less than 4, unless you meant to type less than 5. Even then, I'm not sure what's significant about the existence of a specific type of formula for the roots besides historical interest. (But I'm drawing out this discussion way longer than necessary especially since I'm mostly in agreement with you, so I'll stop now)

Comment: A physicist can tell a student how a polynomial might be used in physics, but a mathematics teacher should be able to talk about mathematical context.  Regarding "less than four": I'm an analyst---I am usually pretty lazy, and use "less than" to mean "less than or equal to", since those two terms are essentially equivalent for all practical purposes in analysis.  It is an error, but you rightly understood the point.  And **yes**, the historical interest is *important*.  Mathematics happens in a context, both historical and theoretical.  Someone teaching the subject should understand that.

Comment: @XanderHenderson In some countries proof-based courses are standard from high school. For instance, when I was at high school I studied the limits with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, the Riemann integral, Rolle’s theorem (just to cite a few things) etc., all with the proofs. And my maths professor asked us to be able to reproduce all the proofs of the year. And when I studied engineering the analysis classes where the same of those for mathematicians, with proofs. So, certain generalizations about what someone with a physics or engineering background  doesn’t know about math are excessive.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Which is why I have been very careful to note that the context of my comments is the American system.  That said, I would expect that the teachers know *more* than they are required to teach.  If proofs are required in high school, then I would expect the teachers to take proof-based classes which go well beyond the kinds of material that they are expected to teach their students.

Comment: @XanderHenderson In fact, the mathematics classes in the first two years of engineering and physics were at the same level of those for mathematicians, making engineers and physicists suited to teach maths at the high school level too. Unfortunately, in recent years, many universities in my country have simplified the mathematical part of the curriculum for engineers and (less so for physicists, afaik).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Then in the context of your country, it seems like it would be reasonable for a physicist to teach math.  Are physics *teachers* held to the same standard as physics *majors*?

Comment: @XanderHenderson What do you specifically mean by _major_? Someone who has a degree in physics? In my country, _engineers_, _physicists_, _chemists_ and _mathematicians_ can all teach physics and mathematics. They might have to follow some a few additional classes about teaching in general before teaching, tough.

Comment: @XanderHenderson To be clearer, I'm talking of people who have a master's degree or a PhD in one of those disciplines.

Comment: Yes, a major is someone with a degree in the field.  But, in the US, at least, one needn't have a degree in mathematics in order to teach high school mathematics.  Similarly, one needn't have a degree in physics in order to teach high school physics.  So a high school physics *teacher* is not necessarily someone with a physics *degree*.  Someone with a physics *degree* is more likely to be qualified to teach mathematics than someone with a high school physics teaching *credential*.  I am trying to determine the extent to which that distinction exists elsewhere.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The question here, as far as I can tell, is about high school teachers.  In your system, how many *high school* teachers have bachelors degrees in the fields that they are teaching, let alone masters or PhDs?

Comment: @XanderHenderson So, in my country, anyone with a master's degree or a PhD in physics, engineering or mathematics can teach mathematics or physics. I'd say that very few have only a bachelor's degree because afaik you cannot get a permanent position with just that (I might be wrong though). Not that having a master's degree or a PhD is sufficient to be good teachers, and in fact there are plenty of bad teachers in those disciplines (I tutored students on mathematics and physics for about 15 years when I was a student, and I saw many bad examples).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano **If** it is true that a masters or PhD in one's field is required in order to teach that topic at the high school level, and **if** the mathematical standards for undergraduate majors in the sciences are as rigorous as you claim, **then** I think that a high physics teacher would likely be qualified to teach high school mathematics.  However, I suspect that the kind of system you describe, as admirable as it sounds, is pretty rare in the world.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Your first question made me quite curious how a non-proof-based course in PDE could look like. I find this surprising since even for most linear PDEs there is no chance to compute the solution (unless the geometry of the problem is extremely simple).

Comment: @JochenGlueck I'm both scratching my head in confusion and shaking it in amazement at the high school students routinely solving linear PDEs.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Hmm, but I don't think anybody claimed that high school students were solving (or should be solving) PDEs, right?

Comment: @JochenGlueck My initial answer was purely concerned with high school (what we call "secondary education" here in the cradle of civilisation). (I am 100% solid in my assertion that you really don't need a high level of mathematical sophistication to teach high school mathematics.) Somehow we seem to have conflated this with PhD work. I suspect that a lot of the fuss is just dust raised by teachers jealously guarding their monopolies on teaching. Well get this, I'm one of those guerrilla illegal teachers poaching their students. Catch me if you can, suckers.

Answer (score 0):

In the USA, I'd say it's common, not ubiquitous, that from K-6, kids get their math instruction from generalist elementary teachers, lacking a math degree, or often even any non-ed degree.  7-12, you usually have dedicated instructors.  So specialization is the norm.  Most of the math teachers tend to have math degrees.  But there's no reason for it to be 100%.  As long as you know the content and have the teaching cert, it's not that hard to move (more likely "be moved") into teaching math versus science.

Usually, it seems like schools struggle harder to find the teaches for the science courses and for computer science.  And there's competition for HS jobs.  So having a subject matter degree is generally desirable.  But I know of people teaching HS math with an undergrad in science.

I even know one with an English degree.  They keep him away from AP Calculus, but he handles algebra and geometry fine.  Not the norm really, but certainly rarely happens.

There's no conceptual reason you can't have an adjunct or even a tenure/track faculty in a university math department, who lacks a math degree.  I'd say it's incredibly rare though.  There's a big supply demand problem (for the jobseekers, it's a blessing for the colleges) in terms of the number of people looking for jobs versus the openings.  So, competition makes it extremely unlikely.

All that said, I have reasonably frequently seen community colleges using non-math UGs to teach night school or summer sessions.  Usually from a science or engineering background and often mid career with a day job.

Comment: It is worth noting that most high school math teachers in the US do not require a mathematics degree (or even a math minor).  It is generally possible to get a secondary education credential in mathematics by taking 10-15 hours of upper division mathematics (along with one's courses on methodology, pedagogy, law, and so on).

Comment: @XanderHenderson In my U.S. state it is possible for a teacher who has achieved baseline certification/preparation to get a credential in any subject (including secondary mathematics) by passing the state teacher certification examination for that subject.

Comment: In my limited experience with American grade school system, most teachers barely know their subject, and so-called science teachers are the worst. They cobble up their single-page leaflets from various internet sites and do not double-check the info, not even on Wikipedia. When questioned why they "teach" incorrect information they would say it is good enough and it will be taught the right way in HS anyway. This is American school system in nutshell: no system, no responsibility.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Can you clarify? This directly contradicts a comment you made on another question which states that "most states in the US require that secondary mathematics instructors have training in mathematics beyond just calculus." Are we talking about the same thing here? In Britain, secondary education is the same as American high-school (approximately, the ages are consistent anyway).

Comment: Incidentally, we don't need to point our pointy fingers solely at the US. When I was aged 7 or 8 in (UK) school, and I questioned the teacher talking about "the four corners of the earth" (I think she was teaching us fairy stories, I can't remember her ever teaching us anything else) and told her I had been led to believe the Earth was spherical. She led the class in laughing at me, saying "But everybody would fall off!" What was worse was she was young, her husband was a cameraman for the BBC so sheltered and isolated she was NOT.

Comment: @PrimeMover I don't see any contradiction.  Can you clarify?